# How to parse a .doc file using a word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am stuck with this word VBA and in need of some assistance.I have 160 word documents in a folder and each .doc contains atleast one phrase like `'IO:'` I want to copy all the file names that starts after `'IO:'` and stop copying when the cursor finds `Report Output:`. Here is one sample input:

---

`Step Name:         Step 3 – GP00BMDR

Step Description::  GENISYS main batch driver which processes external transactions and internal transactions, updates masters, generates transaction records to the accounting subsystem and produces print files.

File Specification:
    Input:  1. GPFTRNW – PHGP.GPFTRNW.TRN.STD.KSDS

```
                   2. GPFSCIM – PHGP.GPFSCIM.SCI.KSDS

                   3. GPFSCSM – PHGP.GPFSCSM.SCS.KSDS


               IO: 1. GPFPDGT – PHGP.GPFPDGT.PDG.TRN.KSDS

                   2. GPFRTXT – PHGP.GPFRTXT.RTX.KSDS
```

Report Output:      Nil`

---

So I want to copy the .doc name and the file names after `IO:` and stops when the cursor reaches `Report Output:` . Here is my script:

```
Sub Ftp_Step_Details()

'this macro checks for FTP in respective steps and copy and writes in a cell along with the     corresponding JCL

Dim wordApplication As Word.Application
Dim wordDocument As Word.Document
Dim flag As String
Dim Folder As String, J As String, FLD As Object
Dim Objfile As Object
Dim objfso As Object
Dim intRow As String
Dim contents As String
flag = True
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strPath As String
    'the dialog is displayed to the user
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
'checks if user has cancled the dialog
If intResult <> 0 Then
    'dispaly message box
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
End If
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\FILE-LIST\File-List.xlsx")
 objExcel.Visible = True
 objExcel.Workbooks.Add
 objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Jcl Name"
 objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "File Names"
 'Folder = "D:\TEST-IO"  'JCL source goes here
 Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set wordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 intRow = 2
 'Opening the file in READ mode
Set FLD = objfso.GetFolder(strPath)
For Each file In FLD.Files
Set Objfile = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file)
   Do While Not Objfile.AtEndOfStream
       contents = Objfile.ReadLine
       If contents Like "*IO:" Then
           flag = True
        End If

       If contents Like "*Report Output:*" Then
           flag = False
       End If
       If flag = True Then
            objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = file.Name
            objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = contents3
            intRow = intRow + 1
       End If

     Loop
  Next
  Objfile.Close
   MsgBox "THANK YOU"
  End Sub
```

---

Now whie testing the code i am getting `TYPE MISMATCH` in the step  `Set Objfile = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file)`   why is that?

Another doubt I have does `Readline` function works in word VBA as well?

Answer (score 0):

> Now whie testing the code i am getting TYPE MISMATCH in the step  `Set Objfile = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file)` why is that?

Because `File` is type `Scripting.File` which is an Object, and the `Documents.Open` method expects a string.

You could try:

```
Documents.Open(file.Path)
```

> Another doubt I have does Readline function works in word VBA as well?

No, I don't think so.

Comment: @DavidZ...THanks for the quick rply so can you tell me what function to use to read the .doc line by line?

Comment: Save it as a TXT file and use the `ReadLine` method?  I don't know if you can read "lines" in Word, I don't think you can.  But you can read *Paragraphs*, and each of those lines might be considered a paragraph.  But generally if all you want is text, don't fuss with a robust DOC object, just convert it to plain text and parse the text simply.